# Rails Object to hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following object that has been created

```
@post = Post.create(:name => 'test', :post_number => 20, :active => true)
```

Once this is saved, I want to be able to get the object back to a hash, e.g. by doing somthing like:

```
@object.to_hash
```

How is this possible from within rails?

Answer (score 346, accepted):

If you are looking for only attributes, then you can get them by:

```
@post.attributes
```

Note that this calls [`ActiveModel::AttributeSet.to_hash`](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveModel/AttributeSet/to_hash) every time you invoke it, so if you need to access the hash multiple times you should cache it in a local variable:

```
attribs = @post.attributes
```

Comment: Don't use this when looping, [Expensive method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attributes#623-Expensive-method-). Go with as_json

Comment: `.to_json` will query DB if model is not complete

Comment: Works with `joins` and `select`,  `Person.joins(:address).select("addresses.street, persons.name").find_by_id(id).attributes`, will return
 `{ 
  street: "",
 name:  ""
 }`

Comment: @AnkitG I don't believe as_json is any less expensive. If you look at the source code for `as_json`, it will call `serializable_hash` which, in turn, will call `attributes`! So your advice is actually adding two layers of complexity over `attributes`, making it even more expensive.

Comment: `.as_json` will serialize the object to ruby hash

Comment: `.to_json` converts everything to strings, whereas `.attributes` retains type information

Answer (score 53):

In most recent version of Rails (can't tell which one exactly though), you could use the `as_json` method :

```
@post = Post.first
hash = @post.as_json
puts hash.pretty_inspect
```

Will output :

```
{ 
  :name => "test",
  :post_number => 20,
  :active => true
}
```

To go a bit further, you could override that method in order to customize the way your attributes appear, by doing something like this :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def as_json(*args)
    {
      :name => "My name is '#{self.name}'",
      :post_number => "Post ##{self.post_number}",
    }
  end
end
```

Then, with the same instance as above, will output :

```
{ 
  :name => "My name is 'test'",
  :post_number => "Post #20"
}
```

This of course means you have to explicitly specify which attributes must appear.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT :**

Also you can check the [Hashifiable](https://github.com/pote/hashifiable) gem.

Answer (score 26):

```
@object.as_json
```

as_json has very flexible way to configure complex object according to model relations

**EXAMPLE**

Model **campaign** belongs to **shop** and has one **list**

Model **list** has many **list_tasks** and each of **list_tasks** has many **comments**

We can get one json which combines all those data easily.

```
@campaign.as_json(
    {
        except: [:created_at, :updated_at],
        include: {
            shop: {
                except: [:created_at, :updated_at, :customer_id],
                include: {customer: {except: [:created_at, :updated_at]}}},
            list: {
                except: [:created_at, :updated_at, :observation_id],
                include: {
                    list_tasks: {
                        except: [:created_at, :updated_at],
                        include: {comments: {except: [:created_at, :updated_at]}}
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        methods: :tags
    })
```

Notice **methods: :tags** can help you attach any additional object which doesn't have relations with others. You just need to define a method with name **tags** in model **campaign**. This method should return whatever you need (e.g. Tags.all)

Official documentation for [as_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)

Comment: Had made a custom function just before finding this.  Wanted more of a single-use method, rather than defining a function for the class. 
 Missed this even after working with the XML serialization methods for some reason.  The `to_` variant seems to work almost exactly the same as the `as_` variant, except for the quoted output.  The only thing I didn't like was not preserving the order of my filter criteria.  It seems to be alphabetically sorted.  I thought that was related to the awesome_print gem I have in my environment, but I don't think that's the case.

Answer (score 12):

You can get the attributes of a model object returned as a hash using either

```
@post.attributes
```

or

```
@post.as_json
```

`as_json` allows you to include associations and their attributes as well as specify which attributes to include/exclude (see [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)). However, if you only need the attributes of the base object, benchmarking in my app with ruby 2.2.3 and rails 4.2.2 demonstrates that `attributes` requires less than half as much time as `as_json`.

```
>> p = Problem.last
 Problem Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "problems".* FROM "problems"  ORDER BY "problems"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Problem id: 137, enabled: true, created_at: "2016-02-19 11:20:28", updated_at: "2016-02-26 07:47:34"> 
>>
>> p.attributes
=> {"id"=>137, "enabled"=>true, "created_at"=>Fri, 19 Feb 2016 11:20:28 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Fri, 26 Feb 2016 07:47:34 UTC +00:00}
>>
>> p.as_json
=> {"id"=>137, "enabled"=>true, "created_at"=>Fri, 19 Feb 2016 11:20:28 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Fri, 26 Feb 2016 07:47:34 UTC +00:00}
>>
>> n = 1000000
>> Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
?>   x.report("attributes") { n.times { p.attributes } }
?>   x.report("as_json")    { n.times { p.as_json } }
>> end
Rehearsal ----------------------------------------------
attributes   6.910000   0.020000   6.930000 (  7.078699)
as_json     14.810000   0.160000  14.970000 ( 15.253316)
------------------------------------ total: 21.900000sec

             user     system      total        real
attributes   6.820000   0.010000   6.830000 (  7.004783)
as_json     14.990000   0.050000  15.040000 ( 15.352894)
```

Comment: as_json will call the database query again, if you are running nested resouce with join metho

Answer (score 6):

You could definitely use the attributes to return all attributes but you could add an instance method to Post, call it "to_hash" and have it return the data you would like in a hash. Something like

```
def to_hash
 { name: self.name, active: true }
end
```

Answer (score 6):

There are some great suggestions here.

I think it's worth noting that you can treat an ActiveRecord model as a hash like so:

```
@customer = Customer.new( name: "John Jacob" )
@customer.name    # => "John Jacob"
@customer[:name]  # => "John Jacob"
@customer['name'] # => "John Jacob"
```

Therefore, instead of generating a hash of the attributes, you can use the object itself as a hash.

Answer (score 2):

not sure if that's what you need but try this in ruby console:

```
h = Hash.new
h["name"] = "test"
h["post_number"] = 20
h["active"] = true
h
```

obviously it will return you a hash in console. if you want to return a hash from within a method - instead of just "h" try using "return h.inspect", something similar to:

```
def wordcount(str)
  h = Hash.new()
  str.split.each do |key|
    if h[key] == nil
      h[key] = 1
    else
      h[key] = h[key] + 1
    end
  end
  return h.inspect
end
```

Comment: Poster is asking about ActiveRecord models in Rails.

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
Hash[ post.attributes.map{ |a| [a, post[a]] } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Swanand's answer is great.

if you are using FactoryGirl, you can use its `build` method to generate the attribute hash without the key `id`. e.g.

```
build(:post).attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but heavily referenced ... I think most people use other methods, but there is infact a `to_hash` method, it has to be setup right.  Generally, pluck is a better answer after rails 4 ... answering this mainly because I had to search a bunch to find this thread or anything useful & assuming others are hitting the same problem...

Note: not recommending this for everyone, but edge cases!

---

From the ruby on rails api ... http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html ...

```
This class encapsulates a result returned from calling #exec_query on any database connection adapter. For example:

result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query('SELECT id, title, body FROM posts')
result # => #<ActiveRecord::Result:0xdeadbeef>

...

# Get an array of hashes representing the result (column => value):
result.to_hash
# => [{"id" => 1, "title" => "title_1", "body" => "body_1"},
      {"id" => 2, "title" => "title_2", "body" => "body_2"},
      ...
     ] ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `instance_variables` method and extend it with `symbolize_keys` method:

```
3.2.1 :001 > @object.instance_values
 => 
 {"attr_1" => "value_1",
  "attr_2" => "value_2"}
3.2.1 :002 > @object.instance_values.symbolize_keys
 => 
 {:attr_1 => "value_1",
  :attr_2 => "value_2"}
```