# Is there some Ruby on Rails method to convert a model object into a HASH structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model User

```
u=User.find(1)
```

How do I get `u` instance converted into a hash? Is there some built-in method to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by converting it to a hash? You may find that the model does what you want anyway.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can already access it via `u['some_field']` syntax.

Answer (score 17):

Answer is here on SO: [Rails Object to hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872236/rails-object-to-hash) (use `.attributes` method)

*I needed this for rspecing update method, since you have to give it a hash as param.*

Answer (score 12):

You can use as_json to achieve what you want.

```
@object = User.find(1)

@object.as_json
```

as_json has very flexible way to configure complex object according to model relations

**EXAMPLE**

We can exclude columns like this too

```
@object.as_json({except: [:created_at, :updated_at]})
```

Official documentation for [as_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)

Comment: And if you want to include certain columns (-_^)
`the_fields_you_want = [:this, :and, :that]`
`@object.as_json({only: the_fields_you_want})`