# Get data of belongs_to field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I don't know how to formulate my question, so here's my problem. I have a model `Vote` which has a `user_id` field.

My `Vote` model is :

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

My `User` model is :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :votes
end
```

So far, nothing fancy.

My problem is that I would to add User's information when I get a vote. Like this

```
@votes = Vote.all
[#<Vote: 
    id: 1,
    user: #<User: id: 1, name: "Foo">
 >]
```

So far, I do it manually :

```
json = []
@votes = Vote.includes(:user)
@votes.each do |vote|
    tmp = vote.attributes
    tmp[:user] = vote.user.attribute
    json << tmp
end
```

Something like that. Is there any way to do it automatically ? Or do I have to create the field manually ? Do you have any idea ?

Comment: You can access a specific votes "parent" user by calling @vote.user

Comment: You do know that vote.user returns the user? It are you looking to customise the output of inspect?

Comment: I update my post. What if I have an array ? How can I build the object to get the User ?

Comment: You can access all of the users attributes through their entry in the users table and you can access that table through the vote.user attribute.  Perhaps you just want to access that information instead of writing it to your vote table in case the information changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find the answer :

```
@votes = Vote.all
@votes.as_json(include: :user)
```

[Rails Object to hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872236/rails-object-to-hash#answer-17852807)