# ruby: add additional parameter to model by map

Tags: ruby

I have a model from database `db_groups = DbGroups.all`

and an array of custom `groups` which comes from some "metadata". with attributes `group.id` and `group.env`

First I'd like to have only db_groups, where `db_group.id = group.id`. I am doing this with:

```
       @metadata['groups'].map do |group|
         db_groups.map { |db| db.id == group.id ? db : nil}
       end.flatten.compact
```

This works fine, so far so good:)

now I'd like to add `env` argument temporary to my `db_groups` model.
so to do something additional like `db_groups[:env] = group.env`

I tried to do this with the "map", but it did't work, so like this:

```
   @metadata['groups'].map do |group|
     db_groups.map { |db| db.id == group.id ? db[:env] = group.env : nil}
   end.flatten.compact
```

what would be the right way to solve this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using rails, you can convert a model to a hash using `as_json`. E.g.

```
db_groups_h = db_groups.map(&:as_json)
```

and then add your attribute:

```
db_groups_h.each{ |db| db[:env] = group.env if db.id == group.id }
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17852807/165753) for details.

Comment: I am getting this: `undefined method []=' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: does `db_groups` contain nils?

Comment: weird, the error suggest we're trying to access a nil. Does `db_groups_h = db_groups.compact.map(&:as_json)` work?

Comment: The issue is that I first want to map `db_groups` to `groups` by id, in you suggestion I just add an element to db_groups, but do not shrink it

Comment: Ah, that's a different issue, just reject the non matching `db_groups_h.reject!{ |d| d[:env].nil? }`

Comment: I solve the issues, retrieving db_groups with a filter form database (so that I did'n need a map after) and then use your suggestion, converting to json and adding a field. Thanks a lot! :)